# move_uploaded_file() could not move file to Google Storage on Google App Engine (php 7.2)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, php-7.2

```
$filename = generate_filename($type, $id);
$filepath = "gs://$bucket.appspot.com/uploadedfiles/$filename";
error_log("trying to move ".$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']." to ".$filepath);
if (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $filepath)) {
        // ...
    } else {
        error_log("could not move the uploaded file");
    }
}
```

This is what I'm seeing in the log:

> trying to move /tmp/php69rSck to
>   gs://my-project.appspot.com/uploadedfiles/sale-image-3-1545631667.1964.jpg
>
> could not move the uploaded file

How can I determine why this is failing?

Comment: What is the file size? What is the error message reported by `move_uploaded_file()` App Engine has a 32 MB file size limit.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've tried with several different images, all of which are under 100k.

Comment: What is the error message being returned by the Google API that you are calling? That will give you a real clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had forgotten to enable the `gs://` stream wrapper:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();
```